Is it possible to extend the concept of level set to functions from $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$?
Let $f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. The level set of $f$ of level $\alpha$ is $$S_\alpha=\{ (x_1,...,x_n)\in\Omega:f(x_1,...,x_n)=\alpha \}$$
I was reading the previous definition and then I wondered, is it possible to extend this definition to functions $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$? Does it even makes sense to have such a definition for functions with $m$ component functions? I think it would be something like $f_j(x)=\alpha$ for $j=1,...,m$, where $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$. But then again, I am not sure if this makes sense at all. I am simply wondering if this definition is limited to functions with only 1 component function or not.

Why not just $f^{-1}({\alpha})$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. ${x\in\Omega:f(x)=\alpha}$?

@Lorago So, the first component function of $f$ would equal the first component of $\alpha $ and so on, right? Something like $f_j(x)=\alpha_i$

Yes, that's right

Ok, thanks! Every definition of level set I've read presents it with functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ but it's nice to know it is not restricted to those functions

You can also phrase it as intersection of level sets of scalar functions. If $f=(f_1, \dots, f_m)$ and $\alpha=(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m)$, then $$f^{-1}({ \alpha}) = \bigcap_{j=1}^m f_j^{-1}({\alpha_j}).$$
